# NP-hardness of partitioning into k sets

Tags: reference-request, partition-problem

Given a multiset $S$ of positive integers and a fixed positive integer $k$, can $S$ be partitioned into $k$ parts with equal sum?

For $k = 2$, this is the well-known Partition problem. For general $k$, this is described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning) as the "multiway number partitioning" problem, and it's claimed there that this problem is NP-hard for every fixed $k$. However, the reference provided there is not satisfactory because it is about a different problem. I also cannot find this problem in Garey and Johnson's "Computers and Intractability: A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness".

Is there a good reference for the NP-hardness of this problem?

Comment: This is not a research level question. Try posting to https://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/53745/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/164884/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  If you post on the wrong site, you can delete the copy on the wrong site before posting on a new site.